Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule "Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode" error
I'm trying to run Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule in an ADO pipeline, and it's consistently giving me this error and nothing more even with -Debug logging:
DEBUG: 9:10:14 PM - [ConfigManager] Got nothing from [DisplaySecretsWarning], Module = [], Cmdlet = []. Returning 
default value [True].
DEBUG: 9:10:14 PM - AddAzureStorageAccountNetworkRuleCommand begin processing with ParameterSet 'IpRuleString'.
##[error]Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

The specific command I'm running:
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "myRg" -Name "myStorageAcct" -IPAddressOrRange @ ("0.0.0.0") -Debug + any number of the extra settings below. These are not valid Azure resources or IPs, but should be sufficient to repro the issue. I'm getting the same issue locally with each of the below configurations:

-Confirm:$false (this resolves the issue locally, but makes no difference in ADO pipeline)
-Force (not recognized)
Running $ConfirmPreference="None" just before the actual Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule line in the same pipeline task
Running $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ '*:Force' = $true; '*:Confirm' = $false } just before the actual Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule line in the same pipeline task
Any of the above + using -IPRule (@{IPAddressOrRange="$myIp";Action="allow"}) instead of -IPAddressOrRange $myIP

Is there a special flag for this module that I'm missing? Has the syntax updated since the previous SO questions were answered?
When running locally, I'm using Win+R and entering "powershell.exe -NonInteractive", then setting the variables I need and running Import-Module Az.Storage before running Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule ...

Looks like you're missing one or more parameters in your call to Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule - PowerShell in Interactive Mode would normally prompt you for them, but since it's in NonInteractive Mode it can't, and that's what the error is telling you. However, it's hard to tell from your logs alone - can you add the actual code you're calling...

Thanks, I've edited it to include the command I'm running: "Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $(UAT_STORAGE_ACCT_RG) -Name $(UAT_STORAGE_ACCT) -IPAddressOrRange $myIP -Debug". The variables do resolve.

And you're sure it's the Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule line causing the error? Have you tried adding a logging line like write-host "done calling Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule" immediately after to ensure it's not a subsequent line raising the error? I can repro the exact error message using, for example powershell -noninteractive -c "read-host", but powershell -noninteractive -c "Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -resourcegroupname $null -name 'bbb' -IPAddressOrRange @()" gives a different error...

Yes, it's definitely that line as that's the only line I run when repro'ing locally. If you have a sample script that'd be great. I'm curious what different error you're getting--the empty list might be a problem, the $null RG name or bbb account name could be causing that other error as well.

This is also the last line of my script, and there is a Write-Host line just before it that executes fine :(

The error I get is Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule : Missing an argument for parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again. - I deliberately left them as invalid values to try to repro the error, but it doesn't reproduce the exact one you see, so I'm kind of out of ideas.

I would try using valid strings like I am. Something as simple as Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "myRg" -Name "myStorageAcct" -IPAddressOrRange @ ("0.0.0.0") -Debug gives the same error

Using AzurePowerShell@5 task
You can use AzurePowerShell@5 task to run Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule and add network rules to your storage account.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '{ARM service connection}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $(rg) -Name $(sa) -IPAddressOrRange "10.0.0.0/7","28.2.0.0/16"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

It works fine in my pipeline:



Using PowerShell@2 task
To run Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule in PowerShell task, you need to install Az module and authenticate to Azure using Connect-AzAccount.
In the example below, I am using a service principle for authentication and add the ip of the current MS-hosted agent to the storage account network rule.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install Az module'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Import-Module Az
      $ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
      Write-Host "The IP address of current agent machine is $ip"
      $clientSecret = "$(Secret)"
      $clientId = "$(ClientId)" 
      $tenantId = "$(TenantId)"
      $resourceGroup = "$(rg)"
      $storageAccount = "$(sa)"
      $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
      $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientId, $securePassword
      Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $Credential
      Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount -IPAddressOrRange $ip


Awesome! I think I had some issue with the list in my setup, I'm no longer getting this issue. I was using PowerShell 5 this whole time, not sure what the diff was, I'll update if I isolate the problem :) thanks so much!
